# OrientDb - export Object database

Tags: java

When I want to export my Object database and I get an error:

```
constructor ODatabaseExport.ODatabaseExport(
           ODatabaseDocumentInternal,
           String,
           OCommandOutputListener
) is not applicable

argument mismatch;
          OObjectDatabaseTx cannot be converted to ODatabaseDocumentInternal
```

Since [ODatabaseExport constructor](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/tool/ODatabaseExport.html#ODatabaseExport-com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseDocumentInternal-java.io.OutputStream-com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandOutputListener-) is only for documents I'm wondering what options do I have obout export / importing database from java.

Answer (score 2):

Since `OObjectDatabase` is a wraper around `ODatabaseDocument` you can easily access the underlying element by method `getUnderlying()` which will return wated `ODatabaseDocumentInternal` on which you can execute export/import.

[See docs for more info...](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/orientechnologies/orient/object/db/OObjectDatabaseTx.html)